# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when filtered by a clustered indexed column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

```
create table test
(
val1 varchar(4) not null,
val2 varchar(4) not null
)
```

having following rows

```
insert into test(val1,val2) values('1111', 'A')
insert into test(val1,val2) values('1111', '50')
insert into test(val1,val2) values('1111', '50')
insert into test(val1,val2) values('2222', '50')
```

when i search data using following query I get the expected result

```
select val2 from test where val2 <> 'A' and cast(val2 as numeric) > 20 and val1 = '1111'
```

but when I create the clustered index using following query

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ClusteredIndex-20140504-185616] ON [dbo].[test]
(
    [val1] ASC
)
```

and then run the above mentioned query that before creating the clustered index gave the expected result, I get this error

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric
```

can any one please tell me where I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can any one please tell me where I'm wrong

You are assuming that the evaluation of the where clause is done left to right and short circuited so the rows where `val2 = 'A'` is excluded before the conversion to numeric.

SQL Server can evaluate the where clause in any order it sees fit.

A rewrite that will make your query work could look like this.

```
select val2 
from test 
where cast(nullif(val2, 'A') as numeric) > 20 and 
      val1 = '1111'
```

`nullif` returns null if `val2 = 'A'` and is therefor safe to convert to numeric for all rows in your table.

Comment: after waiting for a long time for a reply, I found a function "try_convert" from google and changed my query to select val2 from test where val2 <> 'A' and TRY_CONVERT(numeric, val2) > 20 and val1 = '1111' that solved my problem. But I like your explanation and solution rather good and I'll change my entire database according to your suggestion whereever the condition applies.